# How block is c feature and a objective C object at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, block

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH3-SW2) of block says this way:

> Although blocks are available to pure C and C++, a block is also
>   always an Objective-C object.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) also says:

```
Block objects are a C-level syntactic and runtime feature.
```

How can it both be a c runtime feature as well as an objective C object?

I know most object objective-C objects are derived from NSObject to have the memory management routines. We also have NSProxy class which is not derived from NSObject.

Since NSObject's internal implementation is a c struct, I think since blocks being a c run time feature, blocks can be made as a objective C object. But how are they classified as objective C objects?
What kind of  objective C objects are blocks?

Comment: Matt Gallagher has written a topic on it. They are C objects because they have isa pointer and you can send message to them. By the way they are still obj-c objet in c or c++. look at: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Comment: @MrBonjour Thanks for the wonderful link..You can provide that link in the answer section. I will mark them as an answer..